# Tkinter get() function not saving values as float or int variables

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm writing a script that allows me to input values using the tkinter entry widget that will be used to set a function generator.

Whenever I try to use tkinter, instead of just the python input() function, it gives me this error:

```
lowf = int(float(inputlowf) * 10)
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Here's what I've got: (using pywin32 to control the function generator)

```
import win32api, win32con
import time
import win32com.client
import tkinter

def click(x,y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,x,y,0,0)

shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")

master = tkinter.Tk()
tkinter.Label(master, text="Starting Frequency").grid(row=0)
tkinter.Label(master, text="Ending Frequency").grid(row=1)
tkinter.Label(master, text="Increment").grid(row=2)

line1 = tkinter.Entry(master)
line2 = tkinter.Entry(master)
line3 = tkinter.Entry(master)

line1.grid(row=0, column=1)
line2.grid(row=1, column=1)
line3.grid(row=2, column=1)

inputlowf = line1.get()
inputhighf = line2.get()
inputstep = line3.get()

tkinter.Button(master, text='OK', command=master.destroy).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=tkinter.W, pady=4)

tkinter.mainloop()

lowf = int(float(inputlowf) * 10)
highf = int(float(inputhighf) * 10)
step = int(float(inputstep) * 10)

for z in range(lowf,(highf + step),step):

        file = z

        freq = z / 10

        print(freq)

        time.sleep(.5)
```

Comment: You should put the exact error message into the body of this question. (And maybe the title too)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
inputlowf = line1.get()
inputhighf = line2.get()
inputstep = line3.get()
```

These 3 lines execute as soon as you run the script, thus the `inputlowf`, `inputhighf`, & `inputstep` variables contain the empty entry field that is there when you initialize the `Entry` widgets. Try making a callback function that will run whenever you click "OK" which will get the values.

Try this out to see what I mean:

```
import win32api, win32con
import time
import win32com.client
import Tkinter

def click(x,y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,x,y,0,0)

shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")

master = Tkinter.Tk()
Tkinter.Label(master, text="Starting Frequency").grid(row=0)
Tkinter.Label(master, text="Ending Frequency").grid(row=1)
Tkinter.Label(master, text="Increment").grid(row=2)

line1 = Tkinter.Entry(master)
line2 = Tkinter.Entry(master)
line3 = Tkinter.Entry(master)

line1.grid(row=0, column=1)
line2.grid(row=1, column=1)
line3.grid(row=2, column=1)

def callback():

    global line1, line2, line3, master, lowf, highf, step
    inputlowf = line1.get()
    inputhighf = line2.get()
    inputstep = line3.get()

    try:

        lowf = int(float(inputlowf) * 10)
        highf = int(float(inputhighf) * 10)
        step = int(float(inputstep) * 10)

        print lowf
        print highf
        print step

        master.destroy()

    except ValueError:

        print "Error with input"

myButton = Tkinter.Button(master, text='OK', command=callback).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=Tkinter.W, pady=4)

Tkinter.mainloop()
```

Comment: Everything inside of the tkinter loop works now but how do I carry the variable to functions after the tkinter.mainloop()?

Comment: If you want to avoid using classes, you can make the 3 variables global and they will be accessible everywhere. This solution could be simplified using classes. I can provide an example if you would like to see. But if you want to do it the way you currently have it, just add `, lowf, highf, step` to the `global line1, line2, line3, master` line. (Code edited to reflect this change)